# Catholic Saints Who Have Expressed Thoughts Similar to St. Faustina Regarding Chosen Souls

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, souls, st-faustina

There are at least three places in St. Faustina's *Diary* where she writes about the world being maintained by chosen souls; see, for example:

> **926** And the Lord gave me to know who it is that upholds the existence of mankind: it is the chosen souls. When the number of the chosen ones is complete, the world will cease to exist.

> **1434** I learned that the world's existence is maintained by chosen souls;

> **1533** Now I see clearly that chosen souls keep the world in existence

QUESTION: Does anyone know of any other Catholic Saints that have written about the world being upheld by chosen souls; and/or, when the number of chosen souls is complete---the world will cease to exist? Or, perhaps, anything else along these lines?

Thank you.